# How can you use a data created by a python program?

Tags: python, list

I've created a program which gave me a list with list inside, and then I want to print the first element of the first list but when I do it, I have an error which tells me that my list doesn't exist...

My program is:

```
def Prog1():
    f=open("dimer.out","r" )
    m=open("dimer3.out","w")
    g=f.readlines()
    for k in range(len(g)):
        if "Molecular Orbital" in g[k]:
            c=k
    for n in range(c+1, len(g)):
        m.write(g[n])
        if "Density Matrix" in g[n+1]:
            break
    def ReadMatrix(numberOfRows):
        Ci = [];
        for i in range(0,numberOfRows):
            Ci.append([]);
        f=open("dimer3.out","r")
        lines=f.readlines()
        numberOfBlocks = math.ceil(numberOfRows / 5)
        for i in range(0,int(numberOfBlocks)):
            for j in range(i*(numberOfRows+3)+3, i*(numberOfRows+3)+3+numberOfRows):
                array = re.split('\s+', lines[j])
                for k in range(0,len(array)):
                    if re.search("\.",array[k]) is not None:
                        Ci[j - 3 - i*(numberOfRows+3)].append(array[k])
    print('Ci = ',Ci)
    ReadMatrix(int(26))
```

The error appears when I write `print(Ci[0][0])` after `ReadMatrix(int(26))`.
So my question is, how do I use the `Ci` list outside of the program.

Comment: `"The error appears when i write print(Ci[0][0]) after ReadMatrix(int(26))"` - According to the code posted, you never actually do that...

Comment: yes i didn't write because it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass Ci as an argument to ReadMatrix. You can declare Ci in the scope outside the function, call ReadMatrix with Ci as argument and then print Ci as you want.

```
def ReadMatrix(numberOfRows,Ci):
for i in range(0,numberOfRows):
    Ci.append([]);
f=open("dimer3.out","r")
lines=f.readlines()
numberOfBlocks = math.ceil(numberOfRows / 5)
for i in range(0,int(numberOfBlocks)):
    for j in range(i*(numberOfRows+3)+3, i*(numberOfRows+3)+3+numberOfRows):
        array = re.split('\s+', lines[j])
        for k in range(0,len(array)):
            if re.search("\.",array[k]) is not None:
                Ci[j - 3 - i*(numberOfRows+3)].append(array[k])
print('Ci = ',Ci)
ReadMatrix(int(26))

Ci=[]
Readmatrix(numRows,Ci)

print Ci
```